# "Bad key" exception for certificates with exportable private key

Tags: c#, cryptography, certificate, pki

I am trying to encrypt and then decrypt files using asymmetric encryption. I've created a test certificate using makecert and installed it into my personal localmachine store. In future I'll have to install this certificate on several servers, that's why I've created it with "-pe" flag, that is, with exportable private key. The certificates has been successfully created and installed, I see the "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate" note in mmc.

Now I am trying to encrypt data with RSACryptoServiceProvider in .NET 3.5. And it succeeds. But when I am trying to decrypt it, I get "Bad key" exception.

If I create the certificate without "-pe" option, the same code works well for decryption.
Here is the code:

```
RSA rsaKey = (RSA)myCertificate.PrivateKey;
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCsp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)rsaKey;
byte[] plainText = rsaCsp.Decrypt(encryptedText, true);
```

Also I've tried another method, using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs namespace:

```
EnvelopedCms envelope = new EnvelopedCms();
envelope.Decode(encryptedText);
envelope.Decrypt();
byte[] plainText = envelope.ContentInfo.Content;
```

The result was the same...
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 25):

Ensure that the key you're using was created with "-sky Exchange" if using makecert.exe.  Without this, you can only use the key for signing and authentication, not encryption/decryption which is the use case you're implementing here.

Comment: Thank you sir, exactly what I was missing

Comment: This saved the day.. thanks for the answer AND the explanation.